# En HTML, cómo sería correcto explicar la razón por la cual las etiquetas de apertura y cierre no se visualizan en pantalla

Tags: html, html5, xhtml, tags

Cómo explicarían desde lo más básico **porqué los navegadores no representan ni las etiquetas de apertura ni de cierre al leer un documento web** (a diferencia de los editores de código)?

No me refiero a las etiquetas invisibles o ignoradas, estoy hablando del código literal.

Entiendo que las etiquetas son como instrucciones que le dicen al navegador qué significado tiene tal o cual parte del documento ("tal cosa es la cabecera del documento ,tal ota es un salto de línea, tal otra cosa es un párrafo, etc").

Pero lo que quiero entender en profundidad es porqué funciona de esa manera, "invisibilizando" esa parte del código fuente y sí representando en pantalla contenidos como: texto, recursos de imágen y otros multimedia, campos de formularios, tablas, etc.

Es por que sólo tiene en cuenta, al renderizar, todo lo que no sea una etiqueta html válida?
Tendría que investigar más sobre el funcionamiento de los motores de diseño de los navegadores?

Gracias por cualquier orientación.

Comment: como en toda interfaz gráfica, el intérprete (en este caso el navegador), valga la redundancia, interpreta el código asociado (html) y muestra una representación de este con el cual el usuario puede interactuar

Comment: El navegador necesita saber donde abre y donde cierran ciertas etiquetas para saber como representar el contenido (_[armar el árbol del documento](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/HTML_basics)_), sino, le sería imposible saber que elemento contiene a otros. Con respecto a que un elemento sea "visible" depende de los estilos que le apliques o lo que tenga por defecto. Existen etiquetas que el navegador los procesa y renderiza de diferente forma ya que representan "componentes" (nativos) como `<img`, `<input`, `<textarea`, etc.